# Best tool for jar or class obfuscation without need of writing any additional config file

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I'm looking for a tool which will give a acute performance in class or jar obfuscation and can contrive to obfuscate the jar easily. But for few day I stuck on searching for this tool. I know Proguard deserves itself, but I need a tool which will be very friendly and it can able to retrieve all available packages from the jar and show it. So that it will be easy to obfuscate. If I use Proguard I have to manipulate a configuration file called proguard.cfg that will be used during obfuscation and also I have to execute a command line, you know it is not only destructive but also very as tedious as ever. I know there are some available plugins for eclipse which are being used for obfuscation. But it is not acceptable because it is needed to write down a configuration file.

At length I got a tool named [Zelix](http://www.zelix.com) and working well according my requirements. But it can't perform all jar, it is giving some exceptions while analyzing classes and finally ceased to obfuscate.

Anybody can suggest me any other tool which will be better and can perform for all jar. I'm keenly waiting for your reply.

Comment: Throwing any comment is very bad habit without understanding statement. It seems that you can't understand my requirement. A good habit of understanding should be instilled into you. Please read it again, some tools are available mentioned above. If you know any other tool then comment otherwise don't. I want to use obfuscated jar in commercial purpose.

Comment: This question seems perfectly well-obfuscated to begin with. Perhaps your code is similarly written, and does not require any external tool.

Comment: Wow, Germann started off REALLY huffy: "is your code so brilliant" and "or so crap".  If he wants obfuscation, why ask why?  Plus, code obfuscation is commonly available, not something that can cause the apocalypse as you seem to imply.  He said his reason: it's commercial, somebody is PAYING for it, thus DESERVES to be protected.

Answer (score 32):

Here are a few good Jar obfusticators:

- [Pro Guard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)
- [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html)
- [JShrinker](http://www.e-t.com/jshrink.html)
- [CafeBabe](http://home.comcast.net/~shvets/Programs/Tools/CafeBabe/)

and [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Bytecode_obfuscation) is an article on Obfuscation and shows how to use Pro Guard and CafeBabe. [Here](http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/developers-guide/yGuard_obfuscation.html) is a yGuard example. JShrinker is relatively easier thanks to its GUI interface (hence I didn't look for any tutorial).

Comment: JShrinker is working well without giving any error in case of large jar, but it skips many classes which are very necessary. And thank you very much for appreciating.

Comment: @SuvamRoy sorry cant help there, havent really used them in depth. And to be honest its not entirely fool proof, however it does provide some sort of security layer for your source code.

Answer (score 4):

I have used Zelix succesfully in several large projects where there are thousands of classes that get obfuscated. Zelix can fail when it cant find some third party classes you may directly or indirectly refer. You can try excluding the class / package its failing to obfuscate or tell where to find all third party jars if that where it failing

in the Zelix config script add

```
exclude com.abc.Myclass;
```

or

```
fixedClasses com.abc.MyClass;
```

to add third party jars

```
classpath   

"e:/META-INF/ant-1.5.1.jar"
"e:/META-INF/spring.jar"
"e:/META-INF/commons-io.jar";
```

Answer (score 3):

I used proguard that is very friendly. If you are using its GUI version is a very user friendly. You can use this software GUI very easily by running the giu jar of Proguard.

Comment: Can you favour one thing, how to set proguard plugin in eclipse. So that we don't need to follow command lines steps manually. My need is that I just set the plugin in eclipse and all the setting then the rest of task will be done by eclipse. I'll be thankful if give me the steps that I'm actually wanting from you...

Comment: I will give you the steps of doing it....through the command line and also provide you configuration file. But I am not using plugged in through Ecliple. If you want please provide me your email.id..thanks

Comment: it is very easy and you may do it witout any probnlems..

Comment: Thinking you for your appreciation. suvam_roy2006@yahoo.co.in

Comment: I had sent to your mail check it.....and feel free if you are facing any prolems.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscate tools may be some useful for your project. But there is no obfuscate tool that fulfill your desire.I give one option that is [JavaGuard](http://freecode.com/projects/javaguard)  .But it is not sure as you want.