# How to prevent reverse engineering of jar/war/ear file

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

Iam in requirement of preventing jar/war/ear files , we will supply those files to client, and dont want client to reverse engineering the files for any reason. Until he request us.

Please anyone proivde some suggestions or do there any api to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I haven't used it myself, I've heard many mention [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) as a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538637/best-tool-for-jar-or-class-obfuscation-without-need-of-writing-any-additional-co) to make it little more difficult

Comment: do you know any of such tools, Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

if

1. you don't need full Java EE compliance and can use Tomcat
2. Compile to native code

---

then one possible solution would be Exelcior Jet. I've been using their professional edition for a long time for desktop applications but their enterprise edition works for Web applications as well.

http://www.excelsiorjet.com/

Edit: Obfustation tools like ProGuard help to make reverse engineering  difficult (by changing the names of methods and classes) but still it only takes a bit of effort and knowledge to translate back the code. However, if you compile to native code, then it is extremely difficult to reverse engineer. Additionally, you don't need to have Java run time installed on the client machine (which of course is not a problem for you at the moment). 
Excelsior Jet is a tool that compile Java code to native code. It is a bit expensive e.g. USD 1500 for their enterprise version but for some projects it is worth it. They have different versions to compile to Windows native code as well as Linux native code. 
Native code with Excelsior Jet can be optimized as well for different variables such as memory, foot print and distribution size to name a few.

**Summary: By compiling to native code, reverse engineering can be made extremely difficult and costly as compared to obfuscation tools.**