# How to prove the security for a class file in war with out effecting the functionality?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

We wanted to provide the security for the class file in the war file, beuase if you share the war file to customer he can open and see our code by using some de-compiler available in the market. So i want to restrict that, how can i encrypt that class or any some other way to avoid that lap. And that new war(After enabling the security), it should be executed by the web/application server.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Try searching for tools that do Obfuscation. Plenty of them out there and even links on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538637/best-tool-for-jar-or-class-obfuscation-without-need-of-writing-any-additional-co

Answer (score 1):

Honestly though, what makes you think the client will care enough to use man hours to start going through decompiled code?

They buy a licence from you to use your product, they get support from you, they're happy. They're probably not going to be interested in going through the WAR. Your product may seem extra special to you, but trust me, it's not to other people.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what u said is correct, but i got the requirement,So am trying to find the solution, i got the solution, yguard-2.5.1 is a open source tool.

Comment: Just remember, if they really are interested, yguard won't stop anything.